# How to insert php in data chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm trying to add a php variable in data: in chart.js. The examples say `data: [<?php echo $dates ?>],` This will do, but when I try to do this, it immediately gives me an error that < is an unexpected token. which in a way makes sense. I put it in a string `["<?php echo $dates ?>"]`, but then I do not get any results.

```
while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_array($records1)){

    $Timer = date('M, Y', strtotime($stelling['Timer']));
    $Wheight = $stelling['Wheight'];
    $Title = $stelling['Title'];

    $Timers = '';
    $Wheights = '';
    $Titles = '';

    $Timers = $Timers.'"'.$Timer.'",';
    $Wheights = $Wheights.$Wheight.',';
    $Titles = $Titles.$Title.',';

    $Timers = trim($Timers, ",");
    $Wheights = trim($Wheights, ",");
    $Titles = trim($Titles, ",");


}
echo '<script src="script/graph.js"></script>';
```

**The script file:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Time',
            data: ["<?php echo $Timers ?>"],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
```

I expect the graph to show the data that is stored in the variables

Comment: Javascript files are not parsed on the server - they're just sent to the browser as they are (including any PHP, without executing it).  Rename the JS file to a PHP file.

Comment: Great! I haven't thought of that!

Comment: @Archer Could you tell me how to call a php file in a php file? with include?

Comment: That's a very basic thing - you need to get used to searching for things... **[PHP includes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)**

Comment: @Archer Yes, sorry, i got excited, thank you!

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: Simply View Page Source, then you can easily check your printed data according to that you can solve.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous comments, PHP Array are not the same thing as JavaScript array. There are lots of ways this can be done, one is to loop through the `$timers` array in PHP and then convert that to corresponding JavaScript

Assuming the time contains `array('label'=>'Today','data'=>55);`

then you can use `foreach` or `for` to build the corresponding JavaScript array

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    let data=[];// this is a javascript array

    <?php 
    $timersCount=count($timers);
    for($i=0; $i<$timersCount i++){
    ?>
       data.push({
           data:<?php echo $timers[$i]['data']?>,
           label:<?php echo $timers[$i]['label']?>
        });
    <?php
    }?>
</script>
```

There might be typo, i just typed it but you get the idea.
I am assuming you are running the script in a PHP view file.